# Site works responsively on the desktop but doesn't work on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a responsive website (http://tennisterin.com/ua/). It has worked fine before the last update.

Now it works responsively on a desktop but doesn't work correctly on mobile. And  I can't fine the problem.

I have a correct viewport-tag (as you can see) and don't have critical CSS-errors:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
```

I feel I lost something simple but can't understand what.

Dou you have ideas how can I solve the problem here?

Comment: It looks fine on iOS. What exactly do you mean by _" doesn't work correctly on mobile"_?

Comment: Are you working with a revision control system like git?                                                     **Edit**: Looks fine in android 4.2.2 using Chrome

Comment: My Sony Xperia Z1 and LG G3  in Chrome shows me the full version (no mobile) :(

Comment: @helado I do but nothing important have changed there.

Comment: In the future, keep track of code changes using *Git*. That way, you can use `git diff` or `git show` to show the most recent set of changes, allowing you to pinpoint the regression more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found! It was (still) the problem with @media-queries. One-two incorrect values could create a lot of problems. Always check CSS for validation!

I used https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ for validation.
Found a lot of weak points I will need to fix soon.

Thanks all for the time!